# How to check if objects inside an array is empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object, backend

I have an array of objects which will be send to my database. These objects are fetched from separate Api and some of them come back empty.
Hoe do I check if an object within the array is empty and then remove that object.

I tried using a for loop to loop through the array of objects, but this ends up calling the post function several times and sending copies of the array to my database.

```
Promise.all(promises)
        .then(values => {
for(let i = 0; i<= values.lenght; i++){
    if(Object.keys(values[i]).lenght === 0){
        values.splice(i, 1)
     }else{postArray(values)}}})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

This posts the array multiple time and still doesn't work.

Comment: `lenght` !== `length` - is this just a typo? (twice)

Comment: @RandyCasburn ,yes it was. I didn't copy my code, I just tried to recreate what I tried, I had long deleted that from my code. Its embarrasing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a one liner using [.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with `Object.entries().length` removing any object without entries:

`values.filter(o=>Object.entries(o).length);`

Demo:

```js
const values = [{a:'a',b:'b', c: 'c', d: 'd'},{a:'a',b:undefined, c:undefined, d: 'd'},{a:undefined,b:undefined, c: undefined, d:undefined},{a:'a',b:undefined, c: 'c', d: 'd'},{},{a:undefined,b:undefined, c: undefined, d: undefined},{a:'a',b:'b', c: 'c', d: 'd'},{}];

console.log('Filter out empty objects...');
const result1 = values.filter(o=>Object.entries(o).length);
console.log(result1);

console.log('Filter out objects with no values...');
const result2 = values.filter(o=>Object.values(o).every(v=>v));
console.log(result2);

console.log('Do both filters at once...');
const result3 = values.filter(o=>Object.values(o).every(v=>v) && Object.entries(o).length);
console.log(result3);
```

Comment: Its awesome. Just one more thing pls. If I were to equally eliminate object with keys but empty values. how will I do that? There are 4 key value pairs, some of them come back with 1 or no values at all

Comment: Something like this: `values.filter(o=>Object.values(o).length == Object.keys(o).length)` should work. This looks at the number of values and compares it to the number of keys. If they are the same length, there must be a value for every key.

Comment: Let me look into it.

Comment: Three results -1. The first thing you asked for, 2. The second thing you asked for in comment 3. both combined.

Answer (score 0):

```
Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    let postArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i <= values.lenght; i++) {
        if (Object.keys(values[i]).lenght != 0) {
            postArr.push(values[i])
        }
    }
})
```

You can try this.

`postArr` will be your final array